# Event fires in another event

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, dom-events, addeventlistener

On the first click on each section I create an li which contains the content of that section h2 and it has to be an anchor to that section. The problem is that `item.onclick` fires in the `doSomething` method instead of when I click the `li`.

How can I fix it?

PS: I know that the first child of each section is a h2.

```
var list = document.getElementById('cuprins');

var sections = document.getElementsByTagName('section');
var l = sections.length;
var viz = new Array(l).fill(0);

for(var i = 0; i < l; i++)
    sections[i].addEventListener('click', doSomething);

function jump(h){
    var top = h.offsetTop;
    window.scrollTo(0, top);
    console.log(h);
}

function doSomething(e){
    var index;
    for(var i = 0; i < l; i++)
        if(e.currentTarget == sections[i]){
            index = i;
            break;
        }


if(viz[index] == 0){
        var text = sections[index].children[0].textContent;
        var item = document.createElement('li');
        item.innerHTML = text;
        item.onclick = jump(sections[index]);
        list.appendChild(item);
        viz[index] = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: since these li are dynamically added, you'll need to use event delegation to handle the click events.

Comment: `viz[index].onclick();` before `break` in `doSomething` function

Comment: @Cruiser No, as long as the elements are created with `.createElement()` and have event callbacks properly registered, they will respond to their events properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `jump(sections[index]);` is not being assigned as the callback function for `item.click`. Instead it is being executed anytime `doSomething` is called and `viz[index] == 0`.

What then happens is that the return value from calling `jump(sections[index]);` is being assigned as the `onclick` of `item`, but `jump` doesn't return any value, so there is no function registered with `onclick`.

You need to have `jump` invoked when `item` is clicked, so you need the line to be:

```
item.onclick = function() { jump(sections[index]); };
```

So that the outer function is assigned as the event callback and the contents of the function aren't invoked until the event occurs.

Having said that, I would move away from `onXyz` event properties and move to modern, standards-based code with `addEventListener()`:

```
item.addEventListener("click", function() { jump(sections[index]); });
```

Comment: I understand the mistake. Thank you for the answer! It works now.

Comment: @CiobyAndrei Please mark the answer as "the" answer and up vote. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You're executing function and assign the result to `item.onlick` event
Unstead, using the code below will assign function declaration to `item.onclick` event

```
   if(viz[index] == 0){
            var text = sections[index].textContent;
            var item = document.createElement('li');
            item.innerHTML = text;
            item.onclick = function() {
               jump(sections[index])
            };
            list.appendChild(item);
            viz[index] = 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now the function jump has no actual paramater so it won`t know where to jump to

Comment: @CiobyAndrei , Sorry I didn't notice the parameter. Just edited he answer to allow passing parameters